# Android studio: emulator-x86.exe stopped working after creating the window for the emulator

Tags: android, windows-7, android-studio, android-emulator, windows-7-x64

I just installed Android studio, and I am now trying to set up the device emulator. But it keeps crashing in the middle of invoke process.
The error says:

> emulator-x86.exe stopped working in the middle of invoking

I've tried to:

- Change the resolution of the device to 800X600.
- Reduce the size of the Ram by 512 MB.

But it didn't work out.

---

For example, below is the message be in the 'Run' panel in the Android Studio:

```
C:\Users\VAIO\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools\emulator.exe -netdelay none -netspeed full -avd II_Nexus_5_API_16
emulator: device fd:596
HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode
creating window 51 69 385 683
```

I am running android studio on Window 7.

Comment: Did you enable the 'Use host GPU" option?  Can you post the config of your emulator?

Comment: The emulator setting is "RAM 1GB" (VM Heap 64, Internal storage 200, display 720x1280). And my PC setting is "Windows 7 Professional K 64-bit SP1, CPU Intel Mobile Core 2 Duo P8800 @ 2.66GHz, RAM 4 GB Dual-Channel DDR3 @ 531MHz (7-7-7-20), Graphics Nvidia Defaul (1600x900@59Hz) Intel Mobile Intel 4 Series Express Chipset Family (Sony) NVIDIA GeForce 9300M GS (Sony)". (since I reinstalled, I haven't tried to reduce RAM or display. will this time work?)