# Android - emulator-x86.exe has stopped working

Tags: android, android-emulator

**My problem :** I am using a less speed internet so when i reinstalled my windows 8.I Copied the sdk and .android folder to avoid installing updates.I installed the fresh android studio and linked the sdk and .android folder using environment variables.

When i tried to run my android app it shows the error  "emulator-x86.exe has stopped working"

**In event log :** D:\android\sdk\tools\emulator.exe -netdelay none -netspeed full -avd Nexus_5_API_23

Note: The environment variable $ANDROID_SDK_HOME is set, and the emulator uses that variable to locate AVDs.
This may result in the emulator failing to start if it cannot find the AVDs in the folder pointed to by the
given environment variable.
ANDROID_SDK_HOME=D:\android\sdk

**What i Tried :** 
1. reinstall intel haxm
2. tried low resolutions
3. created new virtual device
4. RAM size reduced to 512 mb
System config:
[image]

*I refereed the following :*

[Emulator-x86.exe has stopped working in android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34022445/emulator-x86-exe-has-stopped-working-in-android-studio)

[emulator-x86.exe has stopped working after lauching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30884073/emulator-x86-exe-has-stopped-working-after-lauching)

[Android studio: emulator-x86.exe stopped working after creating the window for the emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28689894/android-studio-emulator-x86-exe-stopped-working-after-creating-the-window-for-t)

[emulator-x86.exe has stopped working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22328402/emulator-x86-exe-has-stopped-working)

Comment: What type of processor is in your computer?  How much RAM is installed?  You can get that info from Control Panel --> System.  Additionally you will want your environmental path to point to both: `C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools` and `C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools`  You can then open up `android.bat` in your command line editor tool to start the emulator process.

Comment: I think you will want to start at the command line with `android.bat update sdk`  That will open up the the Android SDK manager which will show what in actually installed, and will make recommendations for updates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By unchecking **Use host GPU** i solved my problem .. i created a video for the same https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bt6QN6-nGEA